# How are 'DefaultImports' used when trying to import DTOs into typescript using ServiceStack?

Tags: typescript, servicestack

When trying to use the cli tools provided with ServiceStack for TypeScript, I keep running into the `DefaultImports` feature not working as expected, or in any particular useful way. What is the correct way to use this feature?

For example:

```
/* Options:
Date: 2019-02-08...

...
//ExcludeTypes: 
DefaultImports: Example
*/
```

Will output

`import Example;`

This is invalid, the format I expect is `import Example from ExampleModule`. Am I missing something entirely, or is my understanding wrong?

`DefaultImports: Example from ExampleModule` results in the garbled `import ExamplefromExampleModule;`. Putting things in quotes does not help either.

Answer (score 0):

Hare are some popular Examples of different `DefaultTypes` imports:

- [DefaultTypes: 'es6-shim'](https://techstacks.io/types/typescript?DefaultImports=%27es6-shim%27) -> `import 'es6-shim';`
- [DefaultImports: './my-module.js'](https://techstacks.io/types/typescript?DefaultImports=%27./my-module.js%27) -> `import './my-module.js';`
- [DefaultImports: $ from 'JQuery'](https://techstacks.io/types/typescript?DefaultImports=$%20from%20%27JQuery%27) -> `import $ from 'JQuery';`
- [DefaultImports: * as Zip from "./ZipCodeValidator"](https://techstacks.io/types/typescript?DefaultImports=*%20as%20Zip%20from%20%27./ZipCodeValidator%27) -> `import * as Zip from './ZipCodeValidator';`

I've also just added short-hand support for the popular `Symbol:module` import where it will emit:

```
import { Symbol } from "module";
```

This change is available from v5.4.1 that's now [available on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

I can't reproduce your exact issue using the latest versions so I'd recommend first upgrading your tools that you're using to fetch the dtos.

#### npm tools

If using [@servicestack/cli](https://github.com/ServiceStack/servicestack-cli) npm tooling you can upgrade by uninstalling and re-installing it:

```
$ npm uninstall @servicestack/cli
$ npm i -g @servicestack/cli
```

Then check you're using at least **v1.0.7** by checking the version:

```
$ typescript-ref -v

Version: 1.0.7
```

Then you can update any `*dtos.ts` in your directory by running the tool without arguments, e.g:

```
$ typescript-ref
```

Trying this with https://techstacks.io DTOs (running latest [ServiceStack v5.4.1 on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget)) is working as expected using both the new `Symbol:Module` syntax:

```
/* Options:
...
DefaultImports: Zip:./ZipCodeValidator
*/
```

Generates the expected import:

```
import { Zip } from "./ZipCodeValidator";
```

The import you're trying also works:

```
/* Options:
...
DefaultImports: * as Zip from './ZipCodeValidator'
*/
```

Which generates the expected:

```
import * as Zip from './ZipCodeValidator';
```

If it's not still not working for you then you'll need to upgrade the ServiceStack version of the API you're trying to generate DTOs from.

You can check that the tool itself works by generating DTOs from https://techstacks.io which is using the latest version of ServiceStack:

```
$ typescript-ref https://techstacks.io
```

#### dotnet tools

As an alternative to using `@servicestack/cli` npm tool, you can also use the [web or app tool](http://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v5.4#web), install with:

```
$ dotnet tool install -g web
```

And update it with:

```
$ dotnet tool update -g web
```

Check you're running the latest `0.0.16` version with:

```
$ web -v

Version: 0.0.16
```

Then you can use `web ts` in place of `typescript-ref` (or `ts-ref`) npm tools, e.g. install DTOs with:

```
$ web ts https://techstacks.io
```

Update DTOs with:

```
$ web ts
```

Comment: Using `import * as Zip from './ZipCodeValidator';` resulted in:
`DefaultImports: *asZipfrom'./ZipCodeValidator'
*/

import *asZipfrom'./ZipCodeValidator';`

Comment: Why does it appear to work correctly for you, but I get all the spaces removed and a garbled output?

Comment: This still doesn't seem to function as you say it does? @mythz

Comment: @E.Hayden I've provided live links to show the results of each style, you can copy the DefaultImport from each of the links (there should be no import statement). I've also just updated TechStacks to use v5.4.1 MyGet packages where now you can use the new [DefaultImports=Zip:./ZipValidator](https://techstacks.io/types/typescript?DefaultImports=Zip:./ZipValidator) notation. What tool are you using to update the DTOs?

Comment: I'm using the provided plugin for WebStorm, but I have also tried using the CLI. I've tried copying your examples exactly, and it always removes all spaces giving an unusable output.

Comment: @E.Hayden wasn't able to repro your exact issue, I did find an issue from using an older version from using single quotes `'` vs double quotes `"` which was solved by using double quotes e.g. `* as Zip from "./ZipCodeValidator"`, I've updated my answer with how to update the latest tool versions, if you're still having issues you'll need to upgrade your server to use the latest version of ServiceStack.